# symfony authorization not seeing roles

Tags: symfony

I'm very new to symfony and trying to use its security. I think i have everything set up for authenticating users in my database using a login form. I can authenticate a user via doctrine but symfony doesn't seem to see the roles being returned by the user instance even though i've hard coded the roles into the class.

Here is my security.yml file

```
security:
    encoders:
        MyCompany\MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\User:
          algorithm: sha1
          encode_as_base64: false
          iterations: 1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    main:
        entity: { class: MyCompanyMyProjectUserBundle:User, property: username }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        provider: main
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Here is my User entity

```
<?php

class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    private $id;

    private $username;

    private $salt;

    private $password;

    private $email;

    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the roles granted to the user.
     *
     * <code>
     * public function getRoles()
     * {
     *     return array('ROLE_USER');
     * }
     * </code>
     *
     * Alternatively, the roles might be stored on a ``roles`` property,
     * and populated in any number of different ways when the user object
     * is created.
     *
     * @return Role[] The user roles
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the password used to authenticate the user.
     *
     * This should be the encoded password. On authentication, a plain-text
     * password will be salted, encoded, and then compared to this value.
     *
     * @return string The password
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
     *
     * This can return null if the password was not encoded using a salt.
     *
     * @return string|null The salt
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the username used to authenticate the user.
     *
     * @return string The username
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set is_active
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get is_active
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.1.0)<br/>
     * String representation of object
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.serialize.php
     * @return string the string representation of the object or null
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
                $this->id,
                $this->username,
                $this->salt,
                $this->password,
            ));
    }

    /**
     * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.1.0)<br/>
     * Constructs the object
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.unserialize.php
     * @param string $serialized <p>
     * The string representation of the object.
     * </p>
     * @return void
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->salt,
            $this->password,
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user.
     *
     * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
     * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `ROLE_USER` role is hard coded to be returned from `.getRoles()` but i still get a 403 - Access Denied when i visit `/admin` while authenticated.

Comment: Your serializer needs to include roles as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issue with the behavior. It seems to be working as expected from what you describe.

According to the current configuration, in order to access `/admin`, the user requires `ROLE_ADMIN`. If the user only has `ROLE_USER` (as is your scenario), a 403 response is the correct one (403 means the user is successfully authenticated, but failed authorization).

There are two ways you can get the hard-coding to "work" (though I wouldn't recommend it for real world use):

1. Hard code `getRoles()` to return `ROLE_ADMIN`
2. Flip the hierarchy in `security.yml` to be `ROLE_USER: ROLE_ADMIN`

Comment: This is what's confusing me. I dont understand role definitions in the security.yml file at all. What exactly is the key(ROLE_USER) and value(ROLE_ADMIN) in the security file telling symfony. When/where should i reference ROLE_ADMIN?

Comment: The `role_hierarchy` determines how roles inherit each other. In your `security.yml`, it basically says that `ROLE_ADMIN` automatically gets `ROLE_USER` i.e. all `ROLE_ADMIN` are implicitly a `ROLE_USER` also. It's like extending a class; the child inherits all the properties of the parent. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#roles